# Question on breakpoints in VS2010 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS2010 Ultimate.
Having code:

```
//file IntSet.h
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma once
/*Class representing set of integers*/
template<class T>
class IntSet
{
private:
 T** myData_;
 std::size_t mySize_;
 std::size_t myIndex_;
public:
#pragma region ctor/dtor
 explicit IntSet();
 virtual ~IntSet();
#pragma endregion
#pragma region publicInterface
 IntSet makeUnion(const IntSet&)const;
 IntSet makeIntersection(const IntSet&)const;
 IntSet makeSymmetricDifference(const IntSet&)const;
 void insert(const T&);

#pragma endregion
};

//file IntSet_impl.h
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "IntSet.h"

#pragma region ctor/dtor
template<class T>
IntSet<T>::IntSet():myData_(nullptr),
     mySize_(0),
     myIndex_(0)
{
}

template<class T>
IntSet<T>::~IntSet()
{
}
#pragma endregion

#pragma region publicInterface
template<class T>
void IntSet<T>::insert(const T& obj)
{//BREAKPOINT---------------------------<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
/*IF I SET A BREAKPOINT HERE AND AFTER THAT I CHANGE SOMETHING IN THE BODY 
    I'M GETTING MSG SAYING THAT THE BREAKPOINT WILL NOT CURRENTLY BE HIT, AFTER I REBUILD 
    THE BREAKPOINT IS VALID AGAIN*/

 /*Check if we are initialized*/
 if (mySize_ == 0)
 {
  mySize_ = 1;
  myData_ = new T*[mySize_];
 }
 /*Check if we have place to insert obj in.*/
 if (myIndex_ < mySize_)
 {
  myData_[myIndex_++] = new T(obj);
  return;
 }

 /*We didn't have enough place...*/
 T** tmp = new T*[mySize_];//for copying old to temporary basket
 std::copy(&myData_[0],&myData_[mySize_],&tmp[0]);
 delete myData_;
 auto oldSize = mySize_;
 mySize_ *= 2;
 myData_ = new T*[mySize_];
 std::copy(&tmp[0],&tmp[oldSize],&myData_[0]);
 myData_[myIndex_] = new T(obj);
 ++myIndex_;
}
#pragma endregion
```

See linke marked as BREAKPOINT.
Thanks.

Comment: Your title could use some improvement...

Comment: Doesn't seem like a bug... but it's not the optimal way of doing it either... VS is not being able to background compile correctly...

Comment: That is a lot of question marks. But what about this screenful of code is supposed to be a bug? You forgot to put in the question.

Comment: Can you please explain what the issue actually is?

Comment: Voting to close... we aren't paid to try to decipher your unclear question.

Comment: If you guys read the comments in the code you'd see what the question is, even though it's not literal in the form of a question.  He wants to know why the breakpoint is not valid after changing the body of the function.

Comment: @Earlz We aren't paid for answering clear questions either.

Comment: @AaronLS: Yes, but I prefer to know what I'm looking for before I read pages of code. Expecting people to formulate an actual question is hardly an insurmountable obstacle. By answering his question, we are doing him a favor. Why should *we* be the ones jumping through hoops to cater for his laziness?

Comment: Agreed with @AaronLS - "Bears will eat you", "Earlz", "Kent Boogaart", "IVlad", and "Jon Seigel" voted to close this without even reading it to see that the question IS in there. It's a little unclear but this is not that bad guys. Please put effort into things before you just start crapping all over it... :-/

Comment: @jalf: Then somebody should clean up the question and make it more clear (i.e. outside of the code comments), not just close the question.

Comment: @Jaxidian I did discover the question before closing. I even have the power to edit it. But a >100 rep user should know better and it's too difficult for me to edit into a real question.

Comment: @Earlz: I was too harsh in that comment - my apologies. I SHOULD have said, "I suspect ....". I still feel that there was a true question in there that wasn't *too* hard to figure out at all. In that case, I think closing this is FAR too extreme of an action. I certainly understand if you don't want to clarify it yourself because it's too much effort, but that's when you tick it for -1 and explain that he should make the question more clear, and outside of the code block.

Comment: @Jax guess agree to disagree then. I created a meta poll about it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46764/to-close-or-not-to-close-questions-that-are-very-poorly-made

Comment: @Earlz: Thanks for opening that up. Joining you there. :-)

Comment: @Jaxidian: Once again, it's not really our problem. If the OP does not want to make the effort to ask a real question, he shouldn't expect us to jump through hoops to decipher, second-guess, clean up and format his question for him. If you feel like it, go ahead and turn this into a *proper* question, then I'll vote for reopening. But as it stands now, it deserves to be closed.

I don't see why closing is "too harsh". Closed questions can be reopened.

Comment: @Jaxidian: "Please put effort into things before you just start crapping all over it"??? Seriously? Why should we, when the OP obviously didn't? Why aren't you telling the OP to put some effort into his question? Then we'd have a *reason* to do the same.

Comment: @jalf The comment isn't terribly hard to find given it's in all caps and covers 3 lines and is just a small scroll away.  I mean if your argument is that you don't want to read then isn't that irrelevant since you need to read to give a substantial answer?  So I think just not answering would have been more sensible than a vote to close.

Comment: @jalf And maybe a downvote to express your dislike of the poor form of the question, but to label it as "cannot be reasonably answered" was quickly disproven by the fact that someone provided a pretty good answer pretty quickly.

Comment: @AaronLS: No, it was not disproven. There was no question to answer. There was a comment inside the code that *could* be interpreted as referring to the problem (but not in question form) which the OP would like solved. But answering that is guesswork. You're assuming that it's not just a comment left over by the OP who wrote it for himself. You're assuming that even though it's not actually listed *in the question*, it is indeed the question he wants to ask. And that even though it's not in question form, it is the question he wanted to ask.

Comment: @AaronLS, @Jaxidian: Now my question to you two is, **if it pains you so much to see laziness lead to the question being closed, why haven't either of you edited the question in by now?**

Instead of spending so much time arguing that we're being harsh, you could have spent 1.5 seconds fixing the problem, and making the question easily searchable for others with the same problem.

You didn't. Why not?

Comment: @jalf You watch jeopardy too much :)

Comment: @jalf Actually it was disproven.  The question was answered.  You essentially voted that it was unanswerable.  How could something answered if it was unanswerable?

Comment: @jalf I personally only edit posts to correct spelling or fix formatting.  I don't like doodling with someone's actual content.  The issue here I'm concerned with is peoples quickness and misapplication of the close tool, in my opinion.

Comment: @jalf: I do not have the ability to edit it or I would have. As for my quote that you responded "Seriously?" to - I have apologized for it but chose to not delete it to keep the continuity of this discussion going.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change the code while the program is running, the code no longer matches what was compiled, so the debugger is (usually) unable to manage breakpoints until the program is stopped and rebuilt with the new source.

Under some circumstances, Visual Studio supports edit-and-continue debugging where you can edit a file while the debugger is stopped at a breakpoint, then when you resume it will recompile that code and resume with the modified code.

Comment: Since everybody closed this, I can't post a *proper* answer. I THINK all you're seeing is that the breakpoint tooltip thing is just out-of-sync because the background compiler hasn't fully caught up with your changes. I've seen this happen a LOT where the breakpoint icon makes me THINK it won't work but once I start debugging, then it will turn into a filled circle again and it will actually work. I just ignore it and assume it's a Visual Studio bug.

Comment: @Jaxidian Thanks for your answer, but in my case it just skips this breakpoint (do not enter the fnc body).

Comment: @Jaxidian Personally I think that is a bug and I'm going to report that behaviour to VS Team.

Comment: @Jax is right. You're using templates, an after changing those you often need to force a proper re-compile. @Knowing: Something as trivial as a breakpoint probably isn't broken. Assuming it's a bug in the IDE/compiler is the last thing you should be doing.

Comment: @Knowing: If you have made a change and haven't recompiled, why would you even expect it to hit that breakpoint? At that point, your code doesn't match your assembly, and when you're in that state, I wouldn't expect predictability.